# Find the largest index of the minimum in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have an array of positive numbers and there are some duplicates. I want to find the largest index of the minimum value.

For example, if `a=[2, 3, 1, 1, 4, 1, 3, 2, 1, 5, 5]` then `[i, v] = min(a)` returns `i=3`, however I want `i=9`.

Comment: there is no option in matlab's `min` to return last match. You have to loop yourself to find it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using *find* and *min*.

```
A = [2, 3, 1, 1, 4, 1, 3, 2, 1, 5, 5];
minA = min(A);
maxIndex = max(find(A==minA));
```

*min* get the minimun value, and *find* return de index of values that meet the condition *A==minA*. *max* return de maximun index.

Comment: `find(A==min(A), 1, 'last')`

Answer (score 3):

Here's a different idea, which only requires one function, [sort](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html):

```
[~,y] =  sort(a,'descend');
i = y(end)

ans =

     9
```

Comment: Is the sort guaranteed to be stable?

Comment: I guess it is: “The order of the elements in B preserves the order of any equal elements in A.” Not the most efficient solution, but interesting nonetheless.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `imreginalmin` as well with time complexity `O(n)`:

```
largestMinIndex = find(imregionalmin(A),1,'last');
```